# Como pegar um pedaço da URL asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho a seguinte URL:

```
http://localhost:59278/video/categoria/desenho
```

Estou tentando usar o `Url.Action` para montar uma URL que é baseada no valor da URL atual.
Preciso pegar o valor `desenho` da URL.

Como eu posso fazer isso:

```
Url.Action("Index","video",new { categoria = **????** }
```

Comment: Veja se [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97097/20615) é a mesma coisa. Caso não funcione, poste como está sua rota para podermos lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: É isso mesmo, resolveu